# Error: "Object references an unsaved transient instance " but I can't persist that object

Tags: java, hibernate

I get this error:

**org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing**

The object that I have no saved before is this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =  {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="ID_USUARIO_RECLAMA", referencedColumnName = "CODPERSONA")
private Personas idUsuarioReclama;
```

I can't change the CascadeType to All because this object it's in another scheme which I have no permissions to write.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Hibernate won't allow you to persist the object you are trying to persist until there is an object wich owns its foreign key.

So your object A you're trying to persist references Personas B, but B doesn't exist.

Maybe the foreign key referencing Personas can't be null. In that case is impossible to save A without saving B first.

If the foreign key to Personas can be null, you could write it only if the foreign key does not reference anything and after that write the foreign key when you need, but Hibernate won't allow you to break the referential integrity.